# Implementing convolutional neural network backprop in ArrayFire (gradient calculation)

Tags: arrayfire

I modified equation 9.12 in http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html to center the MxN convolution kernel.

That gives the following expression (take it on faith for now) for the gradient, assuming 1 input and 1 output channel (to simplify):

```
dK(krow, kcol) = sum(G(row, col) * V(row+krow-M/2, col+kcol-N/2); row, col)
```

To read the above, the single element of dK at krow, kcol is equal to the sum over all of the rows and cols of the product of G times a shifted V. Note G and V have the same dimensions. We will define going outside V to result in a zero.

For example, in one dimension, if G is [a b c d], V is [w x y z], and M is 3, then the first sum is dot (G, [0 w x y]), the second sum is dot (G, [w x y z]), and the third sum is dot (G, [x y z 0]).

ArrayFire has a shift operation, but it does a circular shift, rather than a shift with zero insertion. Also, the kernel sizes MxN are typically small, e.g., 7x7, so it seems a more optimal implementation would read in G and V once only, and accumulate over the kernel.

For that 1D example, we would read in a and w,x and start with [a*0 aw ax]. Then we read in b,y and add [bw bx by]. Then read in c,z and add [cx cy cz]. Then read in d and finally add [dy dz d*0].

Is there a direct way to compute dK in ArrayFire? I can't help but think this is some kind of convolution, but I've been unable to wrap my head around what the convolution would look like.

Comment: You do realize you are trying to implement a convolve using sum right ? That is very very inefficient. ArrayFire has functions called `wrap` and `unwrap` that'll allow you to convert (strided) convolutions in matrix multiplications. That is what you need to be using.

Answer (score 2):

Ah so. For a 3x3 dK array, I use unwrap to convert my MxN input arrays to two MxN column vectors. Then I do 9 dot products of shifted subsets of the two column vectors. No, that doesn't work since the shift is in 2 dimensions.

So I need to create intermediate arrays of 1 x (MxN) and (MxN) x 9 in size, where each column of the latter is a shifted MxN window of the original with a pad border of zeros of size 1, and then do a matrix multiply.

Hmm, that requires too much memory (sometimes.) So the final solution is to do a gfor over the output 3x3, and for each loop, do a dot product of the unwrapped-once G and the unwrapped-repeatedly V.

Agreed?